# Calling member functions of a class object which is present in header file included

Tags: c++, linux

I am new to the forum i wanted to call a member function of an included header file..Here is code i have written

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "Abc.h"

CAbc *a;//CAbc is a class present in Abc.h

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
int i=10;
float j=15.5;
bool x;
x=a->method(i,j);//method is a member function of CAbc
if(x)
{
    printf("Working Correctly");
}
else
{
    printf("Not Working");
}
```

}

If i compile this using

```
g++ -I/path/to/include code.cpp
```

I get the Error

```
/tmp/cc5JgLfF.o: In function `main':
 code.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `CAbc::method(int,float)'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried giving

```
x=a::method(i,j);
```

for which i get a is not a class or namespace

Please can anyone tell me am i doing it correctly or not?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you are forgetting to include the implementation source/object.

Try this:

```
g++ -I/path/to/include Abc.cpp code.cpp
```

as long as your implementation class for Abc.h corresponds to Abc.cpp.

Regards,
Dennis M.

Comment: will it work even if Abc.cpp is present in /path/to/include and code.cpp is present in (say)desktop or should they be in single directory

Comment: I would test it out, but no. Include works so you can simply use `#include "something.h"` where something.h is in `/path/to/include` In the compile line, you might want to try: `g++ -I/path/to/include /path/to/include/Abc.cpp code.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

Does your make file or whatever link CABC.obj to the whole exe? If so, then you have forgotten to write the implementation (body, definition) of method...

Comment: It is Linux dude, .o files rather than .obj files. And no .exe's. Lol.

Comment: @Maxim: That's why I wrote "or whatever" :)

Comment: It said "make file or whatever". Not .obj file or whatever. Just being a dick. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, make sure there's an implementation of CAbc.method being linked. Additionally, you need to allocate and deallocate the memory for pointer 'a'; at the moment it's uninitialized.

```
 a = new CAbc();
 ...
 del a
```

Comment: That will be his first bug once it links.